# How to fetch status field, changed from and to in worklog of Jira through Python

Tags: python, python-requests, jira, python-jira

I wanted to check if the status of Jira is changed from (eg. Resolved) to (eg. Closed) by the users I mention for the current date.
I tried using `issue.fields.worklog`, then I also tried `issue = jira.issue('issue id' , expand=changelog)`

This is the kind of code I've tried but still couldn't access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQL issues search:

```
query='project = <projectKey> AND status CHANGED TO "Closed" AND status CHANGED BY <user> AND status CHANGED AFTER startOfDay()'

for issue in jira.search_issues(query, maxResults=100, startAt=0):
    print('{}: {}'.format(issue.key, issue.fields.summary))
```

with the keyword CHANGED you can search for issues that have selected field (in your case status) changed. With the predicates TO, FROM, ON, AFTER, BEFORE, DURING, BY you specify what kind of change you are looking for.

*Tested on Atlassian Jira Cloud using API v2 and jira-python v3.0.1.*